# How to invoke an EJB3 in jboss as 4.2 and jboss as 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

we have two ejb3 applications, one in jboss 4.2, the other in jboss 6.1.

and i want to make a client in tomcat that invoke methods from that applications.

it is possible to do that? and what jars i have to use ? those from jboss 4.2 client or jboss 6.1?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to do that.  You will need the Remote EJB client jars for whatever EJB you want to call.  You do not need any specific JBoss jars, just the client jars.  You will probably need a few CORBA settings set on your InitialContext when you look up the EJB like the IIOP address and port for each EJB:

props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "JBOSS_ADDRESS");
  props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "JBOSS_PORT");